# SharePoint Migration API

Tags: azure, content-migration, migrationapi

I am currently working on the newly released SharePoint migration api which includes different power shell commands as mentioned below

```
New-SPOMigrationPackage

ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage

Set-SPOMigrationPackageAzureSource

Submit-SPOMigrationJob
```

Can some one provide detailed explaination and samples covering all paramters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ConvertTo-SPOMigrationTargetedPackage` - Re-maps a previously created file share based package or exported SharePoint package to accurately describe objects in a target web.
- `New-SPOMigrationPackage` - Creates a new migration package based on source files in a local or network shared folder.
- `Set-SPOMigrationPackageAzureSource` - Creates Azure containers, upload migration package files into the appropriate containers, and snapshot the uploaded content.
- `Submit-SPOMigrationJob` - Submits a new migration job referenced to a previously uploaded package in Azure Blob storage into to a site collection.
- `Remove-SPOMigrationJob` - Removes a previously created migration job from the specified site collection.

Detailed syntax and parameters can be found in article 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143608.aspx